# I want to make a query SQL of two tables where it shows me by user the total of points that is to say; to colums name and total points

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, sequel

I want to make a query SQL of two tables where it shows me by user the total of points that is to say; to colums name and total points

this is the user table
[image: user table]

this is the results table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select sum(r.total_points)
        from results r
        where r.user_id = u.id
       ) as total_points
from users u;
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the sum of the points, each user has a score                                               like columns         ID            NAME                TOTAL_POINTS

Comment: I want to get the id of the results table, the name of the user table and the total points of the user from the table results

Comment: @luislalohdz . . . "where it shows me by user the total of points that is to say; to colums name and total points".  This seems like a very reasonable interpretation of what you are asking.